# SQL show for every customers only last invoice number from same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max

I have a table with customers name and sequentially number of invoices in another column, I would for every customer select only row with highest number of invoice document number.

For example I have this scenario:

```
Customer name | DocNum
----------------------    
cust1           1 
cust1           2
cust1           3
cust2           5
cust3           7
cust3           9
cust4           11
cust4           12
```

I would obtain:

```
Customer name | DocNum
-----------------------
cust1                3
cust2                5
cust3                9
cust4               12
```

I have tried some queries but none work properly.

```
SELECT 
    CustName, DocNum, MAX(DocNum) AS "Last invoice number"
FROM   
    TDocHeader
GROUP BY 
    CustName
HAVING 
    MAX(DocNum) > 1;
```

or

```
SELECT 
    CustName, DocNum AS 'Last invoice number'
FROM   
    TDocHeader
WHERE  
    DocNum IN (SELECT Max(DocNum)
               FROM TDocHeader
               GROUP BY CustName)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there :)

Remove the `HAVING` clause, since some customers could have only 1 doc / invoice number. ex: `cust2` in your example above. Also remove the `DocNum` since it's not part of the `GROUP BY` clause.

#### Here's a working SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/117ca7/3

See the output in the bottom after clicking the blue <kbd>Run SQL</kbd> button on the SQL Fiddle page.

[image]

Here's the SQL

```
SELECT CustName as 'CustomerName'
, MAX(DocNum) AS 'Last invoice number'
FROM   TDocHeader
GROUP BY CustName
```

Answer (score 2):

**temp table with data sample**

```
DECLARE @TDocHeader AS TABLE
    (
      CustName VARCHAR(10) ,
      DocNum INT
    )
INSERT  INTO @TDocHeader
VALUES  ( 'cust1', 1 ),
        ( 'cust1', 2 ),
        ( 'cust1', 3 ),
        ( 'cust2', 5 ),
        ( 'cust3', 7 ),
        ( 'cust3', 9 ),
        ( 'cust4', 11 ),
        ( 'cust4', 12 );
```

**Variant posted by @Shiva (optimal)**

```
SELECT  CustName AS CustomerName ,
        MAX(DocNum) AS [Last invoice number]
FROM    @TDocHeader
GROUP BY CustName
```

**Additional variant, just for info**

```
SELECT  TOP 1 WITH TIES
        CustName AS CustomerName ,
        DocNum AS [Last invoice number]
FROM    @TDocHeader
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustName ORDER BY CustName, DocNum DESC)
```

**Another one additional variant, also just for info**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CustName AS CustomerName ,
        MAX(DocNum) OVER (PARTITION BY CustName) AS [Last invoice number]
FROM    @TDocHeader
```